# Objective c : UINavigationViewController unable to load root controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Hello I have a navigation view controller on the Interface builder and have it placed on a window.rootviewcontroller and then I pushed the initialized view controller to it. I used this line here: [window.rootViewController addSubViews:[navigation view]];

The [navigation view] has no view inside.

But if i create a navigation in code and do the same as before, i can have the navigation appears on the screen.

Does anyone know what is wrong? i have linked the navigation with the Interface Builder as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the class correctly for the "viewcontroller" which is visible inside navigationcontroller(in XIB) within the navigationController hierarchy

[image: Check the sample below]

Comment: I did that actually but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

if you want to set RootViewController

```
 self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

//navigationController its is rOotViewControler.
```

if You want to add as SubView.

```
 [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

i hope it'll help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help... Actually that is what i do as well. I tried to use the second line of your code to see how many subviews in the navigation controller but there was 0 subviews.

Comment: @Simon it means your navigationController don't have ViewController .make sure you have created navigationController with ViewController.

Comment: I did push a view controller in to the navigation controlker